# Sub to Duplicate range copies too many times

Tags: excel, vba

I have some vba code that should do the following:

1. Copy/Paste single-column Range from other sheet
2. remove duplicates from this range
3. paste this range under itself 2 times, so there is 3 copies of each unique value copied from the original sheet.

Here is my code for duplicating a range:

```vb
Sub paste_multiple(ByVal copy As Range, ByVal times As Long)
    Dim last_row As Long
    For i = 1 To times
        Debug.Print (copy.Address)
        last_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scratchpad").Range("A:A"))
        copy.copy (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scratchpad").Range("A" & last_row + 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here is the code that calls this function

```vb
Sub generate_SKU_list()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning View").Range("A:A").copy (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scratchpad").Range("A1"))
    Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scratchpad").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates(Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes)

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning View").Range("A:A")) - 1

    Call paste_multiple(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scratchpad").Range("A2:A" & lr), 2)

    Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scratchpad").Range("A:A").Sort(Key1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scratchpad").Range("A:A"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes)
End Sub
```

The output creates 4 copies of each unique value, and I can't figure out why.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your paste_multiple sub only does the required 2 copies, but the second copies the whole duplicate range from the first, resulting in 4 copies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paste_multiple sub only does the required 2 copies, but the second copies the whole duplicate range from the first, resulting in 4 copies.

Here's an alternative

```
Sub paste_multiple(ByVal rCopy As Range, ByVal times As Long)
    Dim Dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dat = rCopy.Value

    For i = 1 To times
        rCopy.Offset(UBound(Dat, 1) * i,  0).Value = Dat
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed your code so it would run to the following:
Sub paste_multiple(ByVal rCopy As Range, ByVal times As Long)
    Dim Dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dat = rCopy.Value

    For i = 1 To times
        rCopy.Offset(UBound(Dat, 1) * i, 1).Value = Dat
    Next i
End Sub

Now, it does no duplication... any advice?

Comment: @TylerP I fixed a couple of typos.  It definately duplicates the passed range now.  If it doesn't work for you check you are passing the correct range to it